# ExtJS: Synchronizing ComboBox and TagField

Tags: javascript, extjs

A client has a request that an applicant be able to make a primary selection from a list of options, but then also multiple selections from the same options. The values in primary and secondary can't overlap.

E.g. two color selection questions:

```
Favorite Color: SELECT  Other Colors: SELECT
```

User picks Favorite Color RED:

```
Favorite Color: RED     Other Colors: SELECT
                ORANGE
                YELLOW
                GREEN
                BLUE
                PURPLE
```

Red is now gone from Other Colors:

```
Favorite Color: RED     Other Colors: ORANGE
                                      YELLOW
                                      GREEN
                                      BLUE
                                      PURPLE
```

User Picks Other Colors GREEN and BLUE:

```
Favorite Color: RED     Other Colors: GREEN BLUE
```

GREEN and BLUE are gone from Favorite Color:

```
Favorite Color: RED     Other Colors: GREEN BLUE
                ORANGE
                YELLOW
                PURPLE
```

User picks a different Favorite Color PURPLE:

```
Favorite Color: PURPLE  Other Colors: GREEN BLUE
```

Other Colors now has RED, but no PURPLE:

```
Favorite Color: PURPLE  Other Colors: GREEN BLUE
                                      RED
                                      ORANGE
                                      YELLOW
```

I was thinking of pairing a combobox with a tag field, but then as you can see it's a hassle trying to keep the stores aligned for both sides. I tried using filters, but they don't seem to work dynamically.

Is there some easier way to do this in ExtJS? Like a tagfield with one store but two input boxes, one limits to one selection, the other allow multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters to filter the stores dynamically.

For the first combobox you need to create a filter which filters out just the single selection.

```
select: function(comb, record) {
    const value = record.get('abbr');
    const otherColors = Ext.getCmp('OtherColors');
    const otherColorsStore = otherColors.getStore();
    otherColorsStore.setFilters([{
        property: 'abbr',
        operator: '!=',
        value   : value
    }]);
},
```

For the secound combobox with multi selection configured you need to create an array of the values which should get filtered out for the first combobox and then use the [`notin` operator](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.util.Filter.html#cfg-operator).

```
select: function(me,records) {
    const favouriteColor = Ext.getCmp('FavouriteColor');
    const favouriteColorStore = favouriteColor.getStore();
    const values = records.map(r => r.get('abbr'));  // creates an array of all colors to filter out
    favouriteColorStore.setFilters([{
        property: 'abbr',
        operator: 'notin',
        value   : values
    }]);
 }
```

[See the working fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2h3d)

Comment: Thank you. The important trick is to duplicate the store so you can apply independent filters. I was using the same store and running into various issues.